# 18.04 "Wine Windows Program Loader" not showing

Tags: wine

[Wine](https://winehq.com) is installed on my Ubuntu 18.04, but I can't open *.exe* Windows files because the "Wine Windows Program Loader" is missing in "Open with another application".

Wine is fully installed. Asking the terminal to install any version (stable, dev, staging, 64, and so on) returns:

> wine [stable, dev, etc.] is already the newest version

`wine --version` says the command "wine" was not found, even though Wine is installed.

I found a thread online saying it was a Ubuntu 18.04 bug and that the following command fixed it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/doc/wine-stable/examples/wine.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

That command initially worked and the "Wine Windows Program Loader" started to show again on the menu, but now it is gone. Using that same command again gives the following output:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/applications/wine.desktop': File exists

Deleting the "symbolic link" with `rm` and using it again does not work. The Program Loader still doesn't show up. I don't know what to do.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YREq3.png)